# Print PowerPoint slides without a margin to One note

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-onenote

Every time I print a PowerPoint slide to One note the slides have a margin around them as if I'm physically printing them. Since One note already positions the printed slides with space between each other and the One note page's edges, I don't need the slides to have an internal margin. Anyway to print without a margin to One note?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

Put PPT in slide sorter view, select the slides that you want to "print" to One Note, then Copy.

Switch to the page in OneNote you want and paste.